# Google Virtual Pageview Setup

Tags: google-analytics

I need some help with the setup of tracking virtual clicks on a submit button. What I need to do is get the referring site, which Google already tracks, and then track if they click on the button. I have setup an onclick for the submit button and setup a goal in Analytics but it is not tracking. I do have the code in place for Analytics in my header to track pageviews.

So what I am trying to do right now with my goal is to track a referring website and then track who clicks on the button. The virtual view I am using for the click is:

```
onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/Orders/Subscription');"
```

Thank you for any help in getting this setup working. I am still working on learning analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `...get the referring site, which Google already tracks` at the time the user clicks the submit button, you will have to read the cookies (the `_utmz` in this case) that GA sets and extract it from there.

Referral data can be obtained from the reports in GA, but if you want it at the time of submit, you'll have to get it from the cookies. Plain vanilla javascript can do this for you, just google it. Or, use whatever language your pages are written in to extract the data from the cookie (PHP and many others have this capability).

Regarding tracking the virtual page view, if the user can submit your form by hitting the enter key, then `onclick` is not desirable. `onsubmit` in the form tag would be better.

If it is still not recording for you, make sure your goal steps are entered into GA correctly (it's quite common to mess this up and GA is not forgiving to even the slightest error) and that you are using the traditional tracking snippet in the head of your document because your example is in the traditional tracking format. You should not mix async and traditional snippets.

To check if GA is even tracking your virtual page, go to the Content, Top Content report and filter by your virtual page. If it's in there, then it's your goal tracking set up. If it's not in there, it's your virtual page tracking on the form itself.

HTH.